# Default ListView with checkbox

Tags: android-listview

I have a Default Listview with checkbox, and the syntax is

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, documents);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here I need to show the first 2 items to be checked by default after loading the data.

Thanks for your valuable time spending on my issue. Thanks

Comment: That is ok vishal, what I need is, using the same ArrayAdapter can't we get the functionality.

Comment: I think it is not possible. ..